# select users with same social security number different badge numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello as the title suggest I need help writing a query that does this. I need to find all the users who have had a badge number change. So in the database there are often two records for the same person but both have a different badge number. Im assuming it's the same person if the social matches.

Table:

```
Badge_no | SSN 
123123 | 387-47-1234
234837 | 387-47-1234 
837532 | 543-45-6392 
584391 | 543-45-6392
```

In this case I would want it to output:

```
837532 | 543-45-6392 
584391 | 543-45-6392
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE SSN IN (SELECT SSN FROM yourtable GROUP BY SSN HAVING Count(*) >=2);
```

That subquery will return SSN's that have more than one record. We use those SSN's to select, again, from the table to get all of the fields associated to them.